# If $B=\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[5]{x^4\sqrt[9]{x^{24}\sqrt[17]{x^{240}...}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, radicals

What value does $\dfrac{B}{x}$ approach?

Source: Select Problems of "Lumbreras Editors"

---

If I divide I get that:

$$\dfrac{B}{x}=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x}{x}.\dfrac{1}{x^2}\sqrt[5]{x^4\sqrt[9]{x^{24}\sqrt[17]{x^{240}...}}}}$$

$$\dfrac{B}{x}=\sqrt[3]{1\sqrt[5]{\dfrac{x^4}{x^4} \dfrac{1}{x^6}\sqrt[9]{x^{24}\sqrt[17]{x^{240}...}}}}$$

$$\dfrac{B}{x}=\sqrt[3]{1\sqrt[5]{ 1\sqrt[9]{\dfrac{x^{24}}{x^{24}}\dfrac{1}{x^{30}}\sqrt[17]{x^{240}...}}}}$$

$$\dfrac{B}{x}=\sqrt[3]{1\sqrt[5]{ 1\sqrt[9]{1\sqrt[17]{\dfrac{x^{240}}{x^{240}}\dfrac{1}{x^{270}}...}}}}$$
Can I assume that $\dfrac{B}{x}$ is approximately 1?

Comment: I don't quite see the pattern in the roots and the exponents. Could you clarify how it continues?

Comment: The problem is as I show it above. It seems that the radicals go like this $3, 3 + 2, 3 + 2 + 2^2, 3 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3$. And the powers of $x$: $1, 1\times4, 1\times4\times6, 1\times4\times6\times10$

Comment: If $a_i$ is the i'th radical from left,... and $b_i$ is the $i$'th power from left, then the pattern is
$a_i = 2a_{i-1}-1$, with $a_1=3$, and $b_i=(a_{i-1}+1)b_{i-1}$ with $b_1=1$. You get $a_i=2^i+1$ and $b_i = 2^{i-1} \prod_0^{i-2}(1+2^k)$. Maybe this helps...

Comment: Pontus, is the problema is about precalculus

Comment: Just because you can push the $\frac1{x^n}$ factor further and further in doesn't _automatically_ mean it disappears. You have to demonstrate in some way that its influence gets smaller and smaller and actually approaches no influence at all as you go inwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B = x^\alpha$ where
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= 
{\small \frac13}(1 + 
{\small \frac15}(4 + 
{\small \frac19}(24 + 
{\small \frac{1}{17}}(240+\cdots ))))\\
&= \frac13 + \frac{4}{3\cdot 5} + \frac{24}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 9} + \frac{240}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 9\cdot 17} + \cdots\\
&= \frac{2}{2\cdot 3}  + \frac{4}{3\cdot 5} + \frac{8}{5\cdot 9} + \frac{16}{9\cdot 17} + \cdots\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^{k+1}}{(2^k+1)(2^{k+1}+1)}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{2^k+1} - \frac{2}{2^{k+1}+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{2}{2^0+1}\\ &= 1
\end{align}
$$
This means $\frac{B}{x} = \frac{x}{x} = 1$.

Comment: What is the fifth term of $\alpha$?

Comment: $\frac{2}{2^4+1} - \frac{2}{2^5+1} = \frac{32}{17\cdot 33} = \frac{32}{561}$